# how many transactions were in 10-minute intervals (SQL, BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to check if there was a situation where there were more than 3 transactions in a 10-minute intervals (it colud be true/false information).

This is my source data:

```
  SELECT 1 AS transaction_id, 2 AS business_id,  '2023-01-16 14:30:00' as transaction_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 3 ,  '2023-01-16 14:30:00'UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 3 ,  '2023-01-16 14:32:00'UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 3 ,  '2023-01-16 14:33:00'UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 2 ,  '2023-01-16 14:41:00'UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 2 ,  '2023-01-16 14:45:00'UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 2 ,  '2023-01-16 15:01:00'UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 1 ,  '2023-01-16 15:41:00'UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 1 ,  '2023-01-16 15:43:00'UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 1 ,  '2023-01-16 15:46:00'UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 1,  '2023-01-16 17:30:00'
```

I wolud like to achieve something like this:

| business_id | 3_or_more_transactions_in_10_minutes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | true |
| 3 | false |
| 3 | true |

How can I achieve this in BigQuery?

I tried firstly generate intervals for further checking with:

```
GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY( min_transaction_date, max_transaction_date,  INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

But I didn't know how to later use it and checks every possible 10-minute intervals

Comment: does big query have `BETWEEN`?

Comment: Yes, it does. I don't know how it could help here

Comment: sorry i misread the question, thought you were checking the time window yourself

Answer (score 0):

You might consider below.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 1 AS transaction_id, 2 AS business_id, DATETIME '2023-01-16 14:30:00' as transaction_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 3 ,  '2023-01-16 14:30:00'UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 3 ,  '2023-01-16 14:32:00'UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 3 ,  '2023-01-16 14:33:00'UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 2 ,  '2023-01-16 14:41:00'UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 2 ,  '2023-01-16 14:45:00'UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 2 ,  '2023-01-16 15:01:00'UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 1 ,  '2023-01-16 15:41:00'UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 1 ,  '2023-01-16 15:43:00'UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 1 ,  '2023-01-16 15:46:00'UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 1,  '2023-01-16 17:30:00'
)
SELECT business_id, LOGICAL_OR(is_over) AS three_or_more_transactions_in_10_minutes 
  FROM (
    SELECT *, COUNT(1) OVER w >= 3 AS is_over
      FROM sample_table
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY business_id 
                     ORDER BY CAST(UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(transaction_date)) / 60 AS INT64)
                     RANGE BETWEEN 9 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
  )
 GROUP BY 1;

+-------------+------------------------------------------+
| business_id | three_or_more_transactions_in_10_minutes |
+-------------+------------------------------------------+
|           1 | true                                     |
|           2 | false                                    |
|           3 | true                                     |
+-------------+------------------------------------------+
```

- `RANGE BETWEEN 9 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` defines logical 10-minutes window frame (interval).
- `COUNT(1) OVER w` counts transactions within a 10-minutes window frame.
- `LOGICAL_OR(is_over)` returns `true` if `business_id` has at least one window frame with 3 or more transactions in it.